# Has a account validation or password reset token really to be unique?

Tags: php, passwords, token, reset

I have to create an email validation and password reset system and therefor I need a token generator. At first I thought that these tokens have to be strictly unique but when I check for hash(token) AND email in the database I do not see why I shouldn't just use a random string with a sufficient length without appending `uniqid()` for example (which would also be quite obvious).

Am I right with this assumption?

Comment: yes they need to be unique and used only one time. If the same user goes and tries to use the same key and isn't/shouldn't be allowed, then that could be a problem.

Comment: Plus, if you're using an AI/PK key from db (which you should), then using a unique key along with the AI/PK, will make it all that much more unique "to the user". Btw, I came back to the question to see if there was anymore activity; there was another comment but it was deleted. The only I saw more was my upvoted comment. I think that that along with this one pretty much (should) answer(s) the question. You can ping me if you want, as I have now left the question for good. Enjoy your Xmas, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, it only needs to be unique for that user.

You could for example as part of your password reset require a username or email address be provided. In that respect your reset token only needs to be unique to that user.

Also, since you don't have to lookup a token in a list of known good tokens for all users it's much faster.

For example, with a globally unique password reset token I either must use some extra detail such as user info to differentiate that token from others or I must search through all known tokens in some way.

With a unique user/hash code I only have to verify the code provided for this user is valid. By comparison you generally will find an array search and even a hashtable lookup will take much more time.

For example, if a user had not initiated a password reset their internal user might look like this compared to if they had. Note in this example we only permit a single most recent password reset request (not multiple):

```
User.getName() = "Bob"
User.getUserName() = "Bob5412"

User.resetPasswordRequestedTime() = null
User.resetPasswordToken() = null
or
User.resetPasswordRequestedTime() = 1482628217
User.resetPasswordToken() = "f7de43859d244439b101df4e02cc4e17"
```

Now I only need to check if the token was valid for the requested user. No need to worry about "Globally unique" anymore.

In my code I may require any password reset request be completed by the user within 4 hours, so if they're request came in after that I would just ignore their request without checking anything.

Comment: Yes, exactly my thoughts. And the token expiration function is definitely something I will implement, as it is a great way to reduce the pool of vulnerable tokens available.